# mui datagrid pagination not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

```
const defaultPageState = {
    isDataGridLoading: false,
    data: [],
    pageNo: 1,
    pageSize: 100
}

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
        pageStateChange('isDataGridLoading', true);
        console.log('page number', pageState.pageNo);
        console.log('page size', pageState.pageSize);
        pageStateChange('isDataGridLoading', false);
    }
    fetchData();
}, [pageState.pageNo, pageState.pageSize]);        

<DataGrid
           rows={pageState.data}
           rowCount={paging.totalRecordCount}
           page={pageState.pageNo - 1}
           pageSize={pageState.pageSize}
           onPageChange={(newPage) => pageStateChange('pageNo', newPage + 1)}
           onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => pageStateChange('pageSize', newPageSize)}
           columns={TABLE_COLUMNS}
           rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
           loading={pageState.isDataGridLoading}
           pagination
           checkboxSelection
           paginationMode="server"
           onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModal) => {
               setSelectedData(newSelectionModal)
           }}
           components={{
               Toolbar: customToolBar
           }}
           componentsProps={{
               toolbar: { minHeight: '10px' }
           }}
       />
```

the loading prop of datagrid doesn't work.. and the pagination doesn't work too.. the rowsPerPageOptions prop doesn't get kicked it displays all the 500 rows at once and the page numbers change alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your variables with useState hook:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

You can't do that on normal consts